# How to add a Toolbar to UITableViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, toolbar

I need to add a Toolbar with a button in it at the bottom of my `UITableView`. I see lots of websites saying that using a `UINavigationController` is the way, but Is there any option that allows me to do this just within the `UITableViewController`?

Comment: Check this answer <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492852/add-toolbar-to-uitableviewcontroller>

Comment: Welcome to SO .Please read this http://stackoverflow.com/faq Make sure you search what you are looking for before asking..Happy coding

Answer (score 10):

Yes, select your `UITableViewController` in your Storyboard and go to `Editor-Embed in-Navigation Controller`

Then select your newly-created `NavigationController` and in its Attributes Inspector check "Shows Toolbar"

[image]

Comment: This is just a 'simulated' attribute - its there for designing the view but does not affect anything

Comment: It does, check it yourself. Only parameters under "Simulated Metrics" are simulated

Comment: I have spent days and days trying to figure that out. Thanks man!