# Add a Toolbar to UITableViewController that does not use storyboards

Tags: xcode, uitableview, toolbar, xib

I have an Xcode Objective-C project that does not use storyboards.

I have the following UITableViewController.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyViewController : UITableViewController

+ (myViewController*)myViewController;

@end
```

I want to drag and drop a Toolbar UI control onto the xib file but when I drop it just flies off the control and will not stay.

I see solutions where if I do the following then it will allow me to drop it on:
**"select your UITableViewController in your Storyboard and go to Editor-Embed in-Navigation Controller.  Then select your newly-created NavigationController and in its Attributes Inspector check "Shows Toolbar""**
[How to add a Toolbar to UITableViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15136123/how-to-add-a-toolbar-to-uitableviewcontroller)

But my project does not use storyboards and therefore this option is not available to me (Navigation Controller is grayed out in the menu)

How can I do this?

Comment: I would add it in code.

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34602994/8441876) answer.

Comment: @Smartcat this is using Swift and my project does not use Swift.